# Is it possible to exclude resources on particular maven goals in spring boot?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot 1.5.3 with multi-module poms where the parent pom has maven packaging as pom, whereas the child pom packages the classes in a war file.

Is it possible to run the maven goal `repackage` to exclude resources, which are otherwise included in the `spring-boot:run` goal?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<build>
    ...
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
            <configuration>
                <addResources>false</addResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    ...
   </plugins>
   ...
</build>
```

See the docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html#).